# How to get IP numbers of guest of our web page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have web site (coded in ASP.NET,c#) and I want to show IP based statistic information of it's pages. I don't want to use other analysis tools (like Google Analytics) .

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In your ASP.NET page you can use Request.UserHostAddress property to get the user's IP address.

Also, you can use IIS logs (by default in C:\Windows\System32\LogFiles\W3SVCxxxxx....)

Answer (score 1):

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress
```

will return the user's IP address as a string.